# Use header file (.h) from a static library (.a)

Tags: android, c++, cmake, static-libraries

I'm trying to use a static library (.a) in another project. I want to make an `#include` of a header from this .a, but i'm with errors.

First, I tried to search .h file in the .a file, in order to understand if it exists under .a and I get:

```
Binary file libtest.a matches
```

So, the header in under the static library. Then, I insert this way in the CMakeFiles.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library(hello-jni SHARED
            hello-jni.c)

# Include libraries needed for hello-jni lib
target_link_libraries(hello-jni
                      android
                      log
                     /home/prvs/android-ndk/hello/jni/app/src/main/cpp/libtest.a
              )
```

However, when I run the app in Android-Studio I got:

```
Fatal error: 'example.h' file not found
```

And I'm importing to the C like this:

```
#include <example.h>
```

In order to import a header file, it is necessary another steps?

Comment: YOu have to set the directory of the headers in the includes directory list of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static library files (`.a` on Unix/Linux `.lib` on Windows) do normally **not** contain headers. Yes, technically it is possible to pack arbitrary files along the object files, but most linkers will just choke on that and refuse to go to work when presented with such an abomination.

The most likely reason that when searching for the header name in the archive matches is, that the header file name is part of the debugging metadata that's part of the library (so that a debugger can translate binary locations to source file locations).

You have to install the headers separately and specify the installation location when compiling as additional include directory.

Answer (score 0):

To use a library you need two things: the compiled code for the library (in a .a file, a .so file, a .lib file, or whatever) and, separately a header file that describes the entry points for the library. In general you can't derive the header from the library.

For example, to use the C++ standard library (which comes with your compiler as some form of library file) you use the standard header files, which have names like "iostream", "string", and so on.

For example, if you have a library that contains compiled code from one source file:

```
// source.cpp
#include <iostream>
void f(int i) {
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

you need a header file that describes that entry point:

```
// mylibrary.h
void f(int i);
```

In every source file that calls `f` you need `#include "mylibrary.h"` and when you link your executable you need to link with the compiled code in the library.